# Ne4j what means the error Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax: Invalid input 'T': expected 'l/L'

Tags: neo4j, rspec-rails

I'm facing the error during the running of my tests in a rails app.
When I run RSpec that error is thrown and cannot understand what is mean and why. All my specs were working correctly and for some reason, I have now that error `Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax: Invalid input 'T': expected 'l/L'` Tried to do a research online but cannot find a solution.

Full error log:

```
Failure/Error: Neo4j::ActiveBase.current_session.query('MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n')

     Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::CypherError:
         Cypher error:
         Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax: Invalid input 'T': expected 'l/L' (line 1, column 13)
       "MATCH (n)
 DETACH DELETE n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the nodes you are trying to remove have relationships? If so, you must deal with them either sequentially or at the same time.

```
match (n)-[:r]->() delete r
match (n) delete n
```

OR

```
match (n)-[:r]->() delete n,r
```

You cannot delete a node and leave an orphan relationship.